# Prove that a continuous real-valued function on a closed interval in R is Riemann Integrable using only a given lemma

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Prove that a continuous real-valued function on a closed interval in R is Riemann Integrable using only the following lemma:

Lemma 1: A real-valued function $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ iff given any $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $|S_1 - S_2| < \epsilon$ whenever $S_1$ and $S_2$ are Riemann Sums for $f$ corresponding to partitions of $[a,b]$ of width less than $\delta$.

This question may already be out there. However, I haven't been able to find it because this proof can be done with other techniques. I am only allowed to use this lemma here. Can anyone explain how this would be done using only this lemma? I'm not quite seeing it at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: What is your starting point, i.e. definition of Riemann integrable.  Is it (1) in terms of Riemann sums $S(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^n f(t_j)(x_j - x_{j-1}$ converging for any choice of intermediate points $t_j$ to a number $I$ as the partition norm $\|P\| \to 0$, or (2) the definition that uses refinements of partitions?  This is easy to prove without the lemma if you use the definition in terms of upper and lower Darboux sums.  Note that all of these definitions are equivalent (although proving that takes some effort).

Comment: I'm honestly not quite sure. All I was given is what I listed above, and told I could only use the lemma (nothing else). I assume any starting point is ok as long as I only use that lemma.

Comment: The forward implication is easy. Use $|S(P_1,f) - S(P_2,f)| \leqslant |S(P_1,f) - \int_a^bf(x) \, dx|+ |S(P_2,f) - \int_a^bf(x) \, dx|$

Comment: Yes and I can say that those are both less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ to make the sum equal to $\epsilon$. I see that part now.

Comment: Well if this is in a class the definition of the Riemann integral must have been given before you were given such a problem.  .Although based on your understanding from previous questions it sounds like you have both.

Comment: Yes it was, and we were given various equivalent definitions. The step function one I posted is an example of one of the definitions I was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reverse implication we can construct a sequence of partitions $(P_n)_n$ and Riemann sums $(S(P_n,f))_n$ where both $\|P_n\| \to 0$ and the Riemann sums form a Cauchy sequence.

Hence, there exists $I \in \mathbb{R}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$  such that $S(P_n,f) \to I$ as $n \to \infty$, and for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geqslant N$ we have

$$\|P_n\| < \delta, \quad |S(P_n,f) -I| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $$

In the above, we could have taken $\delta$ such that $|S(P_1,f) - S(P_2,f)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ when $\|P_1\|, \|P_2\| < \delta$.  If $P$ is any partition where $\|P\| < \delta$, then since we already have $\|P_N\| < \delta$, it follows that

$$|S(P,f) - I| \leqslant |S(P,f) - S(P_N,f)|+ |S(P_N,f) - I| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon,$$

and $f$ must be Riemann integrable.

**Construction of the sequences**

There exists $\delta_1$ such that if $\|P\|, \|Q\| < \delta_1$, then $|S(P,f) - S(Q,f)| < 1$. We can assume $\delta_1 < 1$ and let $P_1$ be any partition with $\|P_1\| < \delta_1$ and $S(P_1,f)$ be any corresponding Riemann sum.

Further, there exists $\delta_2 < \min(\frac{1}{2},\delta_1)$ such that if $\|P\|, \|Q\| < \delta_2$, then $|S(P,f) - S(Q,f)| < \frac{1}{2}$. Let $P_2$ be any partition with $\|P_2\| < \min(\delta_2, \|P_1\|)$ and $S(P_2,f)$ be any corresponding Riemann sum.

Proceeding, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $\delta_n < \min(\frac{1}{n}, \delta_{n-1}) $ along with a partition $P_n$ and Riemann sum $S(P_n,f)$ such that if $\|P\|, \|Q\| < \delta_n$, then $|S(P,f) - S(Q,f)| < \frac{1}{n}$ and $\|P_n\| < \min( \delta_n , \|P_{n-1}\|)$.

Try to finish yourself by proving that $(S(P_n,f))$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I see. So all that is left to do is to show that it is Cauchy, and then the result follows. This makes sense. Thank you!